# Subscribing to multiple partitions in Azure Event Hub using python

Tags: python, azure, events, azure-eventhub

I have created a event hub namespace.
Inside the event hub namespace I created a event hub with 8 partitions.
It has one consumer group - $Default.

I have written the receiver code in python which looks like this.

```
import asyncio

from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import (
    BlobCheckpointStore,
)

BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = "BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME"
EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR = "EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR"
EVENT_HUB_NAME = "EVENT_HUB_NAME"


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # Print the event data.
    print(
        'Received the event: "{}" from the partition with ID: "{}"'.format(
            event.body_as_str(encoding="UTF-8"), partition_context.partition_id
        )
    )

    # Update the checkpoint so that the program doesn't read the events
    # that it has already read when you run it next time.
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

async def main():
    # Create an Azure blob checkpoint store to store the checkpoints.
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(
        BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME
    )

    # Create a consumer client for the event hub.
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,
    )
    async with client:
        # Call the receive method. Read from the beginning of the
        # partition (starting_position: "-1")
        await client.receive(on_event=on_event, starting_position="-1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Run the main method.
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This code I have taken from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal#receive-events) document.
Now I have run this above code in 5 different VMs. So the expectation is all the 5  receivers should process 5 different message simultaneously. Once one message is processed , the receiver which is free should consumer another message. It should continue till someone stops the receiver code.

The problem I'm facing here is , the same message is getting received by multiple receivers and is being processed again and again. My assumption is the checkpointing is not happening not properly. But I don't exactly know why its not happening.
Or is the above code doesn't meet my expectation.

These are the versions I'm using :

> Name: azure-eventhub Version: 5.10.1
>
> Name: azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio Version: 1.1.4

Any information on this would be really helpful. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Checkpoints are not created automatically.  Your application code has responsibility for creating checkpoints as events are being processed by calling `update_checkpoint` on the `partition_context`.     This example demonstrates: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/recv_with_checkpoint_store_async.py#L26

Comment: @JesseSquire , If you look at the sample code which I have tried you can see that I'm updating checkpoint . Still its not working.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that.   Your expectations are off a bit - with 8 partitions, you'd see each VM own between 1 and 2 partitions, each being processed concurrently.  In this case, it sounds like the processors aren't coordinating.   Can you confirm that each instance is using the same storage container?  If so, then this will likely need more discussion than is appropriate for Stack Overflow.  I'd invite you to open an issue in the Azure SDK for Python repository so that we can get the right folks looped in to assist: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues